# How do I remove TIR bands from current stacked ASTER

Tags: raster, envi

How do I remove TIR from already stacked ASTR that has VIS and SWIR bands. I want to do it in ENVI 5.0. Is there a workaround to do this ?

The bands I stacked has VIS, SWIR, and TIR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add your image, go to `File > Save As`.
2. In the dialog box un-collapse the image (click on the <kbd>+</kbd> sign next to the image).
3. Hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button down and deselect the bands that you want to exclude and hit `OK`.
4. In the next dialogue box you can specify the output as a new ENVI or TIFF image.

Comment: Thanks, when i save it out as a TIFF it came out as a black.